# Using java.awt.Paint to load custom image

Tags: java, paint

I need to use the method of *JFreeChart*, that has the following declaration:

```
setShadowPaint(java.awt.Paint paint);
```

The problem is: how to load the image to `paint` my custom image from disk correctly?
All examples I found on the internet do not clarify these moments.

Comment: I tried to use this code http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Loadanddrawimage.htm

Comment: That sample code has nothing to do with `java.awt.Paint`. Did you try a TexturePaint?

Comment: I didn't. Need to google.Thanks.